# select 100 entries by default in selectinput R

Tags: r, shiny

I simply want to select 100 entries on the selectInput by default in R shiny. Is there a logic or anything inbuilt in place to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question lacks enough context to allow others to provide helpful responses. If you provide some more information about what you're trying to do, and some example code to show how you've tried to answer it so far, you'll get better help.

Comment: There is a `selected` argument to `selectInput` that you can modify to have options selected by default.

Comment: By 100 entries I mean on the UI output table, Not the choices or options given in the selectinput.

Answer (score 0):

Check out datatable if you just want to show 100 entries in the table.https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html